# WebLogic "Exceeded stated content length" Error

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a servlet filter that is generating "Exceeded stated content length" errors in WebLogic 10.0. I would appreciate any suggestions to fix this issue please. Details as follows.

The servlet filter resizes images. This error is occurring then writing the contents a FileInputStream (from disk) to response.getOutputStream() :

**java.net.ProtocolException: Exceeded stated content length of 2228
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeStream(ChunkOutput.java:411)**

See the end of this message for the full stack trace.

Our environment is WebLogic 10.0 with Java 1.5 (on Windows XP). However, we have been using this same servlet filter on Tomcat 6, Java 1.6 for over a year so without any problems. Also, we did successfully test a previous version of this servlet filter with WebLogic 8.1.

The content lengths stated in the stack trace errors do accurately match the sizes of the source files on disk. So, I don't know how the content length is getting too large.

The errors occur after loading 6 images each about 2kB in size. So, I did wonder if the issue might be related to  the WebLogic response buffer size which I gather is about 12 kB.

I attempted to increase the response buffer size using the response.setBufferSize() method. However, WebLogic would not accept that command because the response had already started. Does anyone know of a way to configure the default response buffer size in WebLogic?

Below is a simplified version of the code. I did try adding out.flush(), but to no avail. Is there something missing that would cause a problem with WebLogic but not Tomcat?

//----

```
File file = new File(mFileName);
int fileLength = file.length();
response.setContentLength(fileLength);
response.setContentType(contentType);

OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mFileName);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;

while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {

    out.write(buf, 0, count);
}

in.close();

out.close();
```

//----

Thank you.

Regards

Brett S

The full stack trace is:

```
####<3/11/2009 09:52:20 AM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <nmi02> <cgServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1257202340094> <BEA-101019> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@8615a2 - appName: '_workshop_auto_generated_ear_', name: '/', context-path: ''] Servlet failed with IOException
java.net.ProtocolException: Exceeded stated content length of 2228
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeStream(ChunkOutput.java:411)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.writeStream(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:168)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeStream(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:498)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeStream(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:486)
 at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.sendFile(FileServlet.java:407)
 at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.doGetHeadPost(FileServlet.java:231)
 at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.service(FileServlet.java:170)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
 at com.nminnovation.nmf.images.ConverterFilter.doFilter(ConverterFilter.java:98)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
 at com.nminnovation.nmf.util.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:50)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3368)
 at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
 at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Lweblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject;Lweblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject;Ljava.security.PrivilegedAction;)Ljava.lang.Object;(Unknown Source)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2117)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2023)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1359)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your reply Jim.

The solution was to remove response.setContentLength() then add response.flushBuffer()

```
File file = new File(mFileName);
int fileLength = file.length();
//removed this line:
//response.setContentLength(fileLength);
response.setContentType(contentType);

OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mFileName);            
byte[] buf = new byte[ fileLength ];
int count = 0;
while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, count);
}
in.close();
out.close();
//and added this line:
response.flushBuffer();
```

Thanks again.

Regards Brett S

Answer (score 2):

A Google search for

```
weblogic "Exceeded stated content length"
```

turns up a number of hits, the most interesting of which is [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2892264).

In summary, try doing `response.resetBuffer()` after setting the content-length.