# TiHTTPClient: (java.net.ProtocolException): exceeded content-length limit of 439 bytes

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium, androidhttpclient

When submitting a POST request using the HTTPClient for user's authentification in my android app version, i got an error :

```
TiHTTPClient: (java.net.ProtocolException): exceeded content-length limit of 439 bytes
```

this is the request code :

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            try {
                var json_result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                Ti.API.warn("json_result: " + JSON.stringify(json_result));
                if (json_result.Status == 200) {
                    Ti.App.Properties.setBool('loggedIn', true);
                    Ti.App.Properties.removeProperty("catalgSyncDate");
                    Ti.App.Properties.setString("Token", json_result.Model.Token);
                    Ti.App.Properties.setObject("Model", json_result.Model);
                    Ti.App.Properties.setString("authenticationMessage", this.responseText);
                    Ti.App.Properties.setObject("usrobj", user);
                    getUserProfile(json_result.Model.UserId);
                    getTrainingAcquis(json_result.Model.UserId);
                    CheckAuthentication();
                    //Alloy.createController('monCompte').getView().open();
                    //$.loginWin.close();
                } else {
                    $.actInd.hide();
                    $.actIndContainer.hide();
                    showMessage('Echec de connexion', "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect. Veuillez réessayer svp.");
                }

            } catch(e) {
                Ti.API.error("Login : WS exists error : " + JSON.stringify(e));
                $.actInd.hide();
                $.actIndContainer.hide();
                showMessage("Erreur de communication avec le serveur", "Erreur inconnue à survenue durant la communication avec le serveur. Veuillez réessayer svp. Si l'erreur persiste merci de contacter le support.");
            }

        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            //Ti.API.error("Login : Erreur de connexion :" + JSON.stringify(e));
            $.actInd.hide();
            $.actIndContainer.hide();
            showMessage("Erreur de connexion", "Veuillez verifier votre connexion et réessayer svp.");
        },
        timeout : 10000 // in milliseconds
    });
    xhr.open("POST", Alloy.Globals.ws.url.login);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization-Token', AuthorizationToken);
    var device = Titanium.Platform.manufacturer + "," + Titanium.Platform.osname;
    // + "," + Titanium.Platform.version + " " + Titanium.Platform.ostype + " " + Titanium.Platform.architecture + " " + Titanium.Platform.name;
    var params = '{"UserName" : "' + user._userName + '","Password" : "' + user._userPassword + '","IP":"", "Device": "' + device + '", "Mobile" : true, "RememberMe" : true}';
    Ti.API.error("PARAMS : " + params);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xhr.send(params);
```

The few solutions i found was to remove the setContentLength like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672815) for a similar question but i didn't find how to flush the buffer as it said there (there is no such as method in the titanium HTTPClient API)
and i don't know if that's really the good solution for my problem anyway. So please anyone tell me what it could be.